# How to find all the the ['id'] by month in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a huge dataset consisting of collections with fields like this

```json
{"id":"f3fd1b6c",
"originalVersion":"v2",
"rotation":[{"0.5"},{"-0.5"},{"-0.5"},{"-0.5"}],
"scale":[{"1.0"},{""1.0"},{""1.0"}],
"translation":[{"-2.8820719718933105"},{"11.548246383666992"},{"0.0"}],
"timestamp":"2020-03-27T13:28:09.883+00:00"
```

I want to get all the field ids that were created in same month.

So far I have tried using "find" with exact timestamp query

```js
db.collection.find({'timestamp':date})
```

But I want to get all the elements that were created in same month,

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to search records by a given month, you can do a simple `find` with `$month`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $month: "$timestamp"
      },
      3
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oceZSGxGpw8) for your reference.

---

If you want to group by month and group the ids together, you can do like this.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "$month": "$timestamp"
      },
      idsToFetch: {
        "$push": "$id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XXlhm33xC5Q) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the only issue is I am getting "can't convert from BSON type string to Date" error, while iterating through collected ids cursor object

Comment: Are you storing your `timestamp` field as string instead of proper date object? You may need to use `$toDate` converter to convert them into date first like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qBtMkB2aF5v)

Comment: Thanks, again, 

I think there could be some issue with my datasbase, 
I am getting this error now
"passing a time zone identifier as part of the string is not allowed"

Comment: It's more likely a data issue. Some data's `timestamp` field is failed to be parsed by the `$toDate` function. That is the main drawback of the antipattern for storing date as string instead of proper date object. You need to examine your data set to check for the timestamp field for the data issue.